# Spring Hikari DB thread pool stuck in socket read

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-data-jpa

I'm having issues with one of my Java (17) Spring Boot (2.6.3) applications which is backed by an AWS Aurora Serverless v1 (Postgres). Hikari is used, and all settings are default.

The queries being run by the application are fairly simple like this

```
select od.order_item_id,
       od.order_id,
       od.price,
       od.quantity,
       co.created
from order_details od
    inner join created_order co 
      on od.order_id=co.order_id 
where od.order_item_id='123456';
```

Running this query in DataGrip typically gives me an execution time from 50-150ms.

However my application seems to come to a grinding halt when processing a batch of queries (around ~2000). Looking at a JFR recording, I can see that for some reason a single pool thread is stuck in socket read. I also see in my other dashboards that only 1 out of 10 available Hikari connections is being used.

Below is a 5 minute snapshot, and it looks like all application threads are waiting most of the time from what I understand. I have checked my JVM metrics and can see CPU around 40%, JVM Heap around 55% and I can´t find anything that can really explain what I'm seeing here.

Any ideas what might be going on here?
[image: JFR screenshot]

Comment: check the stack trace in JFR to see the details on waiting threads and where it is waiting